# Как создавать базу данных в указанной директории SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Как создавать базу данных в указанной директории?

Comment: То есть ее при создании БД нельзя ВООБЩЕ указывать директорию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать БД и в external хранилище. в своём SQLiteDataBaseHelper'e при создании базы в параметр с именем БД, передайте полный путь директории с именем самой БД и не забудьте про пермишны на запись в external storage. **Но вы должны понимать, что такая БД никак не защищена и вообще по сути не является частью приложения**

```
public MyExternalDataBaseHelper(final Context context) {

    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Пермишны прописать в манифест (или в случае Android M+ вывести диалог с запросом пермишна при открытии приложения)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

По дефолту путь к БД примерно такой `/data/data/com.example.app/databases/mydb.db`

Answer (score 1):

Все достаточно просто. Местонахождение БД определяется вызовом `Context.getDatabasePath()` - все что нужно разработчику, надо просто перекрыть в своем `Activity` вызов этого метода и возвращать путь где будет находиться ваша БД:

```
@Override
public String getDatabasePath(String name) {
   //blah-blah
}
```

Далее при вызове `openOrCreateDatabase()` - будет вызван ваш метод ну и т.д.